# Entire function - exponent?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is an entire function and $ |f(z)| \le e^x \ (z = x + iy) $ throughout the complex plane. What can be said about $ f(z) $?

Comment: It feels like that $ f(z) $ is either exponential or constant zero. Is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\left|e^z\right| = e^x$, we have:
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)}{e^z}\right| \le 1
$$

It follows that $f(z)/e^z$ is entire and bounded, hence constant by [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29). Therefore, $f(z) = \lambda e^z$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, $|\lambda| \le 1$.

Comment: +1. As a nice generalization, if $f$ and $g$ are entire with $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$ for all $z$, then $f$ is a scalar multiple of $g$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Indeed. [This answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/320917/4583) contains a statement and proof of this generalization.