# If $f,g$ analytic and $|f| = |g|$, prove that $f(z) = ag(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f,g$ are a pair of analytic functions on $U$, such that $|f| = |g|$, prove that $f(z) = ag(z)$. Where $a$ is a constant such that $|a| = 1$.

My attempt: I know I need to define an $h(z)$ as the quotient of the two fucntions but I am stuck there. Do I use the zeroes of the functions as was done in this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613524/suppose-f-and-g-are-entire-functions-and-fz-leq-gz-for-all-z-i). If so, why can I assume that they have a zero in the domain $U$. Help needed.

Comment: When you say analytic, do you mean holomorphic ($f,g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$)? And what properties does $U$ satisfy? Is it open? Closed? ...

Comment: If $g \equiv 0$ on some component of $U$, it follows immediately that also $f \equiv 0$ there. Otherwise, the zeros of $g$ are removable singularities of $f/g$.

Comment: I believe based on the question statement, $f,g: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ and we can only assume they are holomorphic on $U$ which is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Liouville's theorem on $\tfrac{f}{g}$.

Comment: Oh wow, I cannot believe I did not see that. It follows immediately from L.T. then by defining $h =f/g$, $h$ bounded by $1$ $\implies h = a$. Then $f = ag$, correct?

Comment: @User52525 Yes, but you have some work to do to show that the quotient is well defined (see Daniel FIscher's comment to your original question).

Comment: Yes, and this is very similar to the argument as in the linked post I believe.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions defined in a region $U$. How can Liouville's theorem be applied?

Comment: @UmbertoP. The quotient is bounded by $1$, so it must be constant by Liouville's theorem. This immediately gives the result.

Comment: What if $U \not= \mathbb C$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yeah, ok, I admit that technically the theorem you should apply is the maximum modulus principle. The fact is that I also call that one Liouville's theorem...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Don't we need to look into the multiplicity of the zeros as well?