# Comparison of entire functions with $f=cg$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, analytic-continuation

> Let $f,g:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic with $|f(z)|\leq|g(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Show that there is a $c\in\mathbb C$ with $|c|\leq 1$ such that $f=cg$.

If $g\equiv 0$ then we trivially have $c=0$. Otherwise, we can write $$|h(z)|:=\frac{|f(z)|}{|g(z)|}\leq 1\,\forall z\in\mathbb C,\,g(z)\neq 0.$$
Since $h$ is bounded it follows from Liouville's theorem that it must be constant with $h(z)=c$ as well as $|h(z)|=|c|\leq 1$ which shows the claim.

However, if $g$ has an isolated singularity $z_0$ then Riemann's theorem on removable singularities implies that it can be removed since $h$ is bounded. Therefore there exists an analytic continuation $\hat{h}$ with $$\left.h\right|_{\mathbb C\setminus\{z_0\}} = \left.\hat h\right|_{\mathbb C\setminus\{z_0\}}.$$ Furthermore $\hat h$ is bounded as well and once again Liouville's theorem implies $\hat h(z)=c$ and thus $|\hat h(z)|=|c|\leq 1$ and therefore the claim follows.

Comment: yes its ok...what is doubt?

Comment: @neelkanth Just looking for some simplifications if possible and other input if it can be improved like explaining what happens with multiple singularities etc. since I am not complete sure.

Comment: all  the singularities of $h$ can be only finitely many removable singularities which can be removed as you discussed...$h$ being entire bounded function and hence constant...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613524/suppose-f-and-g-are-entire-functions-and-fz-leq-gz-for-all-z-i?rq=1

Comment: There is a tiny mistake in that you are talking about isolated *zeros* of $g$, not singularities. It is $h$ that has singularities. And you should consider what happens when $g$ has non-isolated zeros.