# Showing two entire functions are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be entire functions which satisfy $f(0)=g(0)\neq0$ and $|f(z)|\leq|g(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Show that $f=g$.

My approach: 
Since $f$ and $g$ are both entire, we know that $f(z)=e^{g(z)}\neq0$.  Let us suppose that $f'(z)/f(z)=g(z)$.  Then, $f(z)=e^{g(z)}\implies f(z)=e^{\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}}$.  Taking the log of both sides gives $log(f(z))=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ and so $f(z)\log(f(z))=f'(z)$..... and now I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole that does not lead into Wonderland.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/613524/42969.

Comment: Hi Martin!  Why would the hypothesis about $f(0)=g(0)$ be important?

Comment: As demonstrated in the other Q&As, $|f(z)|\leq|g(z)|$ implies $f = cg$ with some constant $c$. Then $f(0) = g(0) \ne 0$ implies that $c=1$.

Comment: Ahhh.... I see.... So in my rabbit trail of nonsense, did I say anything wrong, or did I just get stuck at the last point?

Comment: I do not see how you conclude that $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$.

Comment: Ahlfors derives it on page 193 and 194 in Complex Analysis

Comment: If $f$ is entire without zeros then $f=e^G$ with some entire function $G$. But: 1) $f$ can have zeros, and 2) that function $G$ would be unrelated to the *given* function $g$.

Comment: I see, thank you.  Maybe it is my own stupidity, but I still don't see why $f(0)=g(0)\neq0$ would imply that $c=1$.  Of course $c=1$, I just don't see why that would imply it.

Comment: Substitute $z=0$ in $f(z) = cg(z)$ ...

Comment: Oh, wow, yes, duh.  Thank you!