# Help with $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ so that $f(z)= \lambda \cdot g(z)$ $\forall z \in \Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two entire functions, s.t. $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ $\forall z \in \Bbb C$. I wanna show that it exists $\lambda \in \Bbb C$, with $|\lambda |\leq 1$ so that $f(z)= \lambda \cdot g(z)$ $\forall z \in \Bbb C$.

Let's observe $h:= \frac{f}{g}$, with $g$ not equal to zero. By assumption $\vert h \vert \leq 1$ so all the singularities of h, which are isolated by the identity principle, are removable by the Riemann extension theorem.

Why can we conclude this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613524/suppose-f-and-g-are-entire-functions-and-fz-leq-gz-for-all-z-i?rq=1

Comment: What you added is correct. Which part exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: Why are all the singularities of $h$ isolated by the identity principle? Maybe if I understand this, I will also understand the next sentence.

Comment: The zeros of $g$ are isolated (unless $g$ is identially zero).

Comment: Alright but how now the Riemann extensions theorem comes into the game? Is it because the limit of $h(z)$ when $z$ tends to the isolated zero exists because $h$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes. $h$ is bounded so that all its singularities are removable. That is Riemann's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, either $g$ vanishes identically (and in this case the conclusion is trivial, since both $g$ and $f$ are $0$) or it has isolated zeroes.

In the latter case, the quotient $h$ is in modulus $\le1$ and defines an holomorphic function on the whole plane minus a discrete set (the zeros of $g$). By Riemann thm, as pointed out, $h$ extends across these isolated singularities to an entire function which is then bounded.
Then by Liouville theorem $h$ is constant, that is, $\exists \lambda\in\Bbb C$ such that $0<|\lambda|\le1$ such that $h\equiv\lambda$.
Since $h=f/g$ you get the conclusion.